# Error: ORA - 47410: Realm violation for GRANT on SOME ROLE

Tags: database, oracle, stored-functions

I have created a function (CREATINGUSER) in a schema (OWNER) with the scope, among others, of creating users and also granting specific rights (for example CONNECT, etc.). I have another schema (SLAVE) which has execute right to OWNER.CREATINGUSER. If I call OWNER.CREATINGUSER from SLAVE, I'm getting some error for role granting

> ORA -47410: Realm violation for GRANT on ROLENAME

. 
Moreover if I call OWNER.CREATINGUSER from OWNER everything runs smoothly. 
Please help me with some advice on how to deal with the above mentioned problem.

Sincerely,

Comment: are you using Database Vault to secure things?

Comment: How can I check if Database Vault is in place?