# Can't revoke an user role

Tags: oracle

I have an role which which exists in sys.dba_roles, and it is assigned to an user. When I want to revoke the role from the user who has it  however I'm getting the error:

> ORA-01924: role 'MY_ROLE' not granted or does not exist.

When I check the roles for the user with problems with:

`SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTEE='MY USER'` the role it's still there.

How can I remove the role, or see which schema owns it ?

Sincerely,

Comment: please post the output from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS. also, post the revoke statement.

Comment: Do you use SQL Developer ? We can go through the parameters it's easier.

Comment: If this is related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47309164/146325) (seems likely) then it looks like you are running with Database Vault enabled. If so, you need to check whether there are any pertinent DV policies in place.

Comment: How this role were granted to user - directly or via other role?

Comment: @FoxCy Yes I use Sql Developper, can you please tell at what parameters I should look?

Comment: @APC Can you please tell how I can check what policies are in place or if the Database Vault is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

On your SQL Developper :

1. Connect with the user name who has the rights to Revoke a role user
2. Decline to the last folder called "Other users" and developed the folder.
3. Search the user
4. Right click on it and then "Edit user"
5. You will have a tab called "Granted Roles", go on.
6. Look for the role you want to remove and then uncheck it in the "Grant" 
   column.
7. Finally valid by clicking on the button OK.

Try like this.